# Batch scan a lot of pictures

Tags: linux, scanner, batch

I have a lot of pictures to scan.

Is it possible, using linux and xsane, to write a script so that the computer will keep scanning, giving incremental filenames to the resulting files ?

I'd really like something that just keep scanning, or, even better, that waits for me to press any key to scan the next picture.

Comment: How does your scanner work? Since it won't help you much if it doesn't automatically takes the next picture :S

Comment: I want to scan, put the next image on the window, press a key, repeat.

I found scanimage, maybe I'll write the script myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the **`scanimage`** program has batch scanning built in, so no scriping is required:

```
scanimage --format=tiff --batch="/path/to/scanned_image-%d.tiff" --batch-prompt
```

See the [man page](http://www.sane-project.org/man/scanimage.1.html) for more info.

> *"The **--batch** options provide the features for scanning documents using document feeders."*
>
> *"**--batch [format]** is used to specify the format of the filename that each page will be written to."*
>
> *"**--batch-prompt** will ask for pressing RETURN before scanning a page. This can be used for scanning multiple pages without an automatic document feeder."*

Comment: Wow, that's weird. The first image is correctly scanned, but once I press enter, the scanner makes a weird noise, and the scanning thingie moves very slowly ...

Comment: I've created another question for that problem. http://superuser.com/questions/22776/weird-noise-wihile-scanning-using-scanimage-and-a-canon-lide-35

Comment: @nasseg: That should be --batch="/path/to/scanned_image-%d.tiff" - missing the equals gives an error.

Comment: Note that if you don't mention the document size (using `-x` and `-y` options of `scanimage`), all pages of the ADF may be seen as a single page.