# Weird noise while scanning, using scanimage and a Canon Lide 35

Tags: linux, scanner, xsane, canon-lide

I'm trying to scan a bunch of images, using xsane's *scanimage* :

```
scanimage --format=tiff --batch --batch-prompt
```

This command scans the first picture perfectly, but as soon as I press enter, the scanner makes a weird noise, and the scanning "arm" moves very, very slowly.

If I stop *scanimage* and start again, it scans normally again.

Is there another *scanimage* option that I need to add? I've checked the man page, but can't see what I'm missing.

**Edit**: the problem seems to be that the scanning "arm" doesn't go back to it's original position after the first scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this link, http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=525963, where the guy has the same problem :

> leads to the optical array moving very
>   slowly and the motor making lots of
>   noise while doing so (after scanning
>   the first page). Interrupting the scan
>   (CTRL-C) doesn't help, one has to
>   unplug the scanner.

It seems to be a libsane bug, fixed in the next version.

Ok thanks.

*I've got to stop answering my own questions. :)*

EDIT : Got it to work by downloading the following packages from the next version of Ubuntu :

- [libsane_1.0.20-4ubuntu2_i386.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libsane)
- [libgphoto2-2_2.4.6-1ubuntu5_i386.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libgphoto2-2)
- [libgphoto2-port0_2.4.6-1ubuntu5_i386.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libgphoto2-port0)

Comment: How unlucky is that; I've got to wait for libsane 1.0.20, which is in debian unstable, which will be in Ubuntu Karmic (still in Alpha).